# Android web view can't play video in iframe?

Tags: android, iframe, android-webview, android-video-player, vk

I am trying to play vk.com videos on android webview. I used video enabled web view that is on [there](https://gist.github.com/benvium/5907542). It can play some videos but mostly not or get long time. And in the logcat says.
"INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported"

Any idea or how can I play that videos?